# PDF invoice layout change / question

Tags: layout, pdf

I'm trying to find out how I can modify the PDF invoice layout on Magento. All I need to do is shift the 'SHIP TO:' box a little to the right so that it prints correctly on the labels that we use.

Can anyone help with this?

[image: invoice]